# Font not the same on mobile vs. desktop

Tags: html, css

I just made published my website and noticed that the font does not appear the same on mobile and on desktop. The weird thing is that some of the text on mobile is in the correct font, while some of it is not. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Edit: For clarification, my site looks fine when I inspect it (on my laptop) and use Chrome's tool to mimic different mobile displays. However, when I open the site on my phone, some of the styling doesn't look the same.

Answer (score 0):

Dario try linking it with Google fonts if it's available on the Google site. It should work universally on most devices whether or not the font is installed on the users computer.

Comment: I think I have linked it, I put the code for the Poppins font in the head of html document I have. Thanks for the response